# ANRs - com.google.android.apps.wellbeing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, anr

I get this `stack trace` from the Google Pre-Launch report:

**Here is `ANR` report**

> ANR in com.google.android.apps.wellbeing;PID: 1269;Broadcast of Intent
> { act=android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED flg=0x1200810
> cmp=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing/.focusmode.manager.impl.FocusModeRefreshStateBroadcastReceiver_Receiver
> };

Detected on 1 device during testing.
The device:

> Google Pixel 2 (virtual) 1080x1920 Android 13 (SDK 33)

Why is it causing an ANR? My app has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sometimes you get false positives in the logs.  I'd ignore it.  Especially if it was only seen once.

Comment: Perhaps this issue is related to SDK 33.

Comment: I had the exact same, I'll ignore it for now

Comment: @VaheGharibyan Did you solve it? I get it too from google

Comment: No @Idan I don't have any solution, but as I understand well-being app sends some intent for tracking app data usage then failed, but why is ANR I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider that is a problem with Google Play Store testing devices. That problem went away without me making any changes on a new release.

Comment: Do you think? how can we over it? they reject mine too

Comment: You can prepare a new build without any changes and release on Google Play Store.